# IOS Chrome can't display page top after redirect by new page link(_blank)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

If I open the link with a new tab, it can't auto-scroll to the page top(*header area*) at the beginning

< a href="." target="_blank">link< /a>

https://youtu.be/fw5tHeEA6So
Operations Link

- Click 'link' that target set to '_blank'
- redirect but it can't display the header area of page top
- Click browser's address bar(0:06)
- Click the cancel button of address bar
- Page shows the header area correctly

---

```html
<div style="min-height: 123px;">
  HEADER
</div>
<div style="min-height: 666px;">
  <a href="." target="_blank">link</a>
  <br /> CONTENT
</div>
<div style="min-height: 200px;">
  footer
</div>
```

---

If I open the link in the same tab, it can auto-scroll to the top by the browser correctly.

< a href="." target="_self">link< /a>

https://youtu.be/8RCGOPlFECs

***Operation Steps***

- Click 'link' that target set to 'self'
- redirect and can display the header area of page top

```html
<div style="min-height: 123px;">
  HEADER
</div>
<div style="min-height: 666px;">
  <a href="." target="slef">link</a>
  <br /> CONTENT
</div>
<div style="min-height: 200px;">
  footer
</div>
```

---

Chrome version: 85.0.4183.109

Comment: I have a similar issue (chrome iOS) - opening a link with target="_blank" causes the content to not fit on the page.  This doesn't occur if the link opens in the same tag.  Interestingly, if I move between browser tabs or switch the orientation and switch it back, it fixes itself.